# Configuring Traefik for docker containers using Cloudflare wildcard and origin

Tags: cloudflare, lets-encrypt, traefik

Do you have to use Let's Encrypt for SSL?  I previously used NGINX and was able to achieve SSL Full (strict) through Cloudflare just using the origin cert and private key with wildcard.  Is this doable with Traefik?  Any reference documents?

Right now, I have Strict SNI enabled and on a subdomain I get an error that no certificate was found for domain my.domain.com (real domain redacted).

I have the cert and key referenced in the .toml.  I get a 526 error in cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

ok, if anyone else finds this, the documentation is confusing.

just add

```
[file]
[[tls]]
  entryPoints = ["https"]
  [tls.certificate]
    certFile = "path/to/my.cert"
    keyFile = "path/to/my.key"
```